# Swift - How can I read a two-dimensional array produced with json_encode?

Tags: php, ios, arrays, swift

This is my php:

```
$query->bind_param("s", $consulta);
$result = $query->execute();
$query->bind_result($row1, $row2);

if($result)
{   
    $json_response = array();
    while ($query->fetch()) 
    {
        $json_response[] = array("NUMERO" => $row1, "IMAGEN" => $row2);
    }
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

This is my arrangement:

```
[
 {"NUMERO":99512233,”IMAGEN”:”\/imagen.jpg”},
 {“NUMERO":99887766,”IMAGEN”:”\/imagen.jpg”},
 {“NUMERO”:99557744,”IMAGEN”:”\/imagen.jpg”}
]
```

And so I am trying to read the arrangement:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
if let parse_json = json
{
    print(parse_json[“NUMERO”][0]) //99512233
}
```

how can i read this?

Comment: Be more clear. Read what? Is your code not working? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by doing the following:

```
$json_response = array();
if($result)
{   
    while ($query->fetch()) 
    {
        $json_response[] = array("NUMERO"=>(string)$row1,"IMAGEN"=>(string)$row2);
    }
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

In xcode:

```
    _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url_request)
    {(data, response, error) in
                      if(error != nil)
                        {
                            print("Error != nil")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if let status_code = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                            {
                                if status_code.statusCode >= 200 && status_code.statusCode < 300
                                {
                                    var json_result = NSArray()
                                    do
                                    {
                                        json_result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        print("Error al convertir el arreglo")
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                        return
                                    }

                                    var json_element = NSDictionary()
                                    for x in 0 ..< json_result.count
                                    {
                                        json_element = json_result[x] as! NSDictionary
                                        if let numero = json_element["NUMERO"] as? String,
                                           let imagen = json_element["IMAGEN"] as? String
                                        {
                                            print(numero + " " + imagen)
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            //No se pudo convertir
                                            print("Nada que mostrar")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Error de servidor
                                    print("No se pudo establecer una conexion")
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("No se pudo convertir el URLResponse")
                            }
                        }
 }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you show:

```
[
 {"NUMERO":99512233,”IMAGEN”:”\/imagen.jpg”},
 {“NUMERO":99887766,”IMAGEN”:”\/imagen.jpg”},
 {“NUMERO”:99557744,”IMAGEN”:”\/imagen.jpg”}
]
```

...looks to me like an array containing multiple dictionaries.

Try casting your JSON output to the desired type:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, 
  options: .mutableContainers)
guard let parse_json = json as? [[String:Any]] else { 
  print("Unable to cast JSON to expected type")
  return
}
print(parse_json[0][“NUMERO”]) //99512233
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the method does not flag error but returns an empty array -> "Index out of range"

Comment: Ok, you need to step through your code in the debugger and examine the data you're getting back. Log the contents of `parse_json` with the command `e parse_json` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to turn the parsed JSON into a NSDictionary, then you can access the keys and the values of the NSDictionary like so: 
`json.value(forKey: "NUMERO")`

Comment: It looks like his data is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary.